# UWP ease in animation on grid size change

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml, windows-10-universal

I have the following Ui and clicking on the "Admin login" button will extend the grid by adding another field ("Device owner") below the password field.
When this happens the outermost grid grows in its height and it's so sudden.

What I'm expecting is when the "Admin login" button is been clicked the height change should animate with an 'ease in' animation.
I tried with storyboard and AnimationBuilder but since the height change is dynamic I don't know how to set the "To" value. Any help would be appreciated.

The "Admin login" button's logic is just to set the visibility of the "Device owner" grid.

Since I'm not setting the height property this code is useless.

```
storyboard1 = new Storyboard();
var AnimationOne = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame() { KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(AnimationTime)), Value = GridHight, EasingFunction = new QuarticEase() { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseIn } };
var AnimOne = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
AnimOne.EnableDependentAnimation = true;
AnimOne.KeyFrames.Add(AnimationOne);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(AnimOne, "(FrameworkElement.Height)");
Storyboard.SetTarget(AnimOne, LoginGrid);
storyboard1.Children.Add(AnimOne);
storyboard1.Begin();
```

I prefer to have the animation via XAML and no code is involved. But at this point, I'll accept anything. :) Thank you for your consideration.

Initial

[image]

After the button clicked

[image]

Comment: What have you tried already? You should post the code you've tried, then others can check and try to improve it.

Comment: I'll update the question. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please the code about how you changed the grid size and added extra controls?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Hi, it's better if you can show me a simple way of doing an animation to cater to my requirement. I'm not fluent in UWP animations. All I do is show and hide the "device owner" section and I want to animate the height change when that happens. Thank you.

Comment: Well, you could check [Storyboarded animations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/motion/storyboarded-animations) about how to create an animation. But I can't be more specific like giving the animation code because I do not know the exact scenario.  It's unknown to me how you changed the grid size when you say `height change being dynamic`.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT First pic has 2 fields visible and one field hidden. When the button clicks I show the hidden field as well. (2nd picture) So when the 3rd field is showing the outer grid's height gets increased. I need to animate that height change.

Comment: @SurenSaluka. I know the requirement based on your image. But I still want to ask, how do you change the size of the grid when you make the 3rd field visible? What do you mean by "height change being dynamic"? Is the size of the 3rd field dynamic? You did not make a clear statement about these things which I've asked in my last comment.

Comment: Yes. That's why I can't determine the before and after the height values that need to be provided to the animation 'To' and 'From' values.

Comment: Why the size of the 3rd field is dynamic? Why not give it a height?

Comment: It contains multiple controls which may or may not be available depending on conditions.

Comment: `When this happens the outermost grid grows in its height and it's so sudden.` How do you change the grid height when not using animation?

Comment: It will better if you could share the code snippet that you are using, just the code that could reproduce the behavior.

Comment: I have no code written coz I don’t know an approach. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Well, I mean the code of the XAML control that shows the three fields, you could share the code snippet so we could understand how you build the XAML.

Comment: If you don't want to share the code, the simplest way is to give height to the controls inside the 3rd field. Then create the animation in code-behind. Calculate the total height manually for the controls that you want to show and use that value as target value of the animation.

Comment: Why not make that a non-scrollable listview for and observable collection of fields. First column textblock, second text box. when the user presses the admin button, the additional item is added for device owner. Because it's using the built in function  of adding a list item; it will ease in nicely.